# Reorder toolStrip items within the same toolStrip without holding the ALT Key pressed in C# VS 2008

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripbutton

I have a toolStrip1 placed on a Form (System.Windows.Forms) in C# and added five toolStrip buttons to it. Now I wonder how to let the user reorder these buttons by dragging them on another positions within the toolStrip1. I set the **toolStrip1.AllowItemReorder to true** and the **AllowDrop to false** as Microsoft in an article suggests.

Now shall be enabled automatic handling of item reorder in the toolStrip1. But it doesn't work - only if I hold ALT-Key pressed the toolStrip1 reacts to the reordering attempts by the user. 
Have I really to handle the **DragEvent, DragEnter, DragLeave** myself for avoid holding the Alt Key during reordering the items?

If it so, please give me an example how this events would look like on a toolStrip with toolStripButtons, if I wish to drag the one item on a different position within the toolStrip1 without holding any ALT Keys (like Internet Explorer Favorites does). I am not experienced in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you may have to use this solution which is a little hacky. The whole idea is you have to **press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key by code**. I've tried with `MouseDown` event (even in a `PreFilterMessage handler`) but it failed. The only event is suitable to hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key when it's fired is `MouseEnter`. You have to register the `MouseEnter` event handler for all the `ToolStripItems`, when the mouse leaves one of these items, you have to release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in the `MouseLeave` event handler. After the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is released, we have to send the `ESC` key to make the form active (otherwise, all the hover effects seem to be ignored, even on the Control buttons including `Minimize, Maximize, Close`). Here is the code which works:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
  public Form1(){
     InitializeComponent();
     //Register event handlers for all the toolstripitems initially
     foreach (ToolStripItem item in toolStrip1.Items){
        item.MouseEnter += itemsMouseEnter;
        item.MouseLeave += itemsMouseLeave;
     }
     //We have to do this if we add/remove some toolstripitem at runtime
     //Otherwise we don't need the following code
     toolStrip1.ItemAdded += (s,e) => {
        item.MouseEnter += itemsMouseEnter;
        item.MouseLeave += itemsMouseLeave;
     };
     toolStrip1.ItemRemoved += (s,e) => {
        item.MouseEnter -= itemsMouseEnter;
        item.MouseLeave -= itemsMouseLeave;
     };
  }
  bool pressedAlt;
  private void itemsMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (!pressedAlt) {
            //Hold the Alt key
            keybd_event(0x12, 0, 0, 0);//VK_ALT = 0x12
            pressedAlt = true;
        }
  }
  private void itemsMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (pressedAlt){
            //Release the Alt key
            keybd_event(0x12, 0, 2, 0);//flags = 2  -> Release the key
            pressedAlt = false;
            SendKeys.Send("ESC");//Do this to make the GUI active again
        }            
  }
}
```